# Why would a Tor site need my EMail,does this not defeat the Tor anonymity?

Tags: tails, windows

I want to volunteer to be a Tor Relay,but all the mumbo-jumbo about using two flash drives or a DVD, I just do not seem to get to work! Do they sell a Tor Relay disc? And what are safe emails to use if I have to sign-up on a Tor site, or is this a FBI sting trick? It seems if you use a email it beats the purpose of Tor! Safe email that prides itself in the American dream of "PRIVACY" ? Anyone who can give me some EMail providers to research or welcomed $$$$

Answer (score 1):

yes, it defeats your anonymity! Tor site is *a site* that works by itself, Tor is *just* a transport. All the anonymity precautions for websites are applied

Answer (score 1):

You have confused two things. Tor is designed to protect the anonymity of a person who uses the Tor network to connect to a remote site.

The network does not, and cannot, protect the anonymity of a person who runs a relay. Why not? Because when you run a relay, your IP must be publicized to the Tor network so that your relay can be used in the construction of Tor circuits. Once your IP is publicized, someone will easily figure out who it is who is running the relay.

If, for some reason, it is illegal to run a Tor relay in the place where you live, don't do it! Help Tor in some other way, perhaps by donating to someone who *can* legally run a relay the money that you would have spent on running one yourself.

Comment: So by giving out my Email address on Tor,it is protected by Tor?Cause sites On the dark web ask for Email address,cause I wanna learn blackhat tricks of the trade.

Comment: I would help greatly if you wrote clearly and asked a clear question. To be clear, you can be a user of Tor, or you can run a Tor relay. It is of course possible for a person both to be a user and to run a relay but the actions are separate. If you are a user, your anonymity is protected to the maximum extent that the design of Tor (and your approach to using it) allows. But as I said in the answer above, if you choose to run a relay (which no one is forcing you to do), then it is not possible to do so anonymously. That is simply an unavoidable feature of the design of Tor.